# How do I split start and end dates with other start and end dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've written two queries below with results that look similar to this:

table : company_changes

| user_id | start_at | end_at | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 189 | 2020-12-12 | 2021-03-02 | 88 |
| 189 | 2021-03-02 | 2050-01-01 | 169 |

table: enablement_changes

| user_id | start_at | end_at | enablement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 189 | 2020-12-12 | 2021-10-15 | disabled |
| 189 | 2021-10-15 | 2050-01-01 | enabled |

It is important that I know when users are at a certain `company_id` and are either `enabled` or `disabled`.

My desired results are a table like this:

| user_id | start_at | end_at | company_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 189 | 2020-12-12 | 2021-03-02 | 88 | disabled |
| 189 | 2021-03-02 | 2021-10-15 | 169 | disabled |
| 189 | 2021-10-15 | 2050-01-01 | 169 | enabled |

I essentially want to combine the results of those queries together. The 2050-01-01 is an arbitrary date in the future. Since the `user_id` has not changed `status` or `company_id` then it shows as 2050-01-01 because it is the user's present state.

Any idea how to approach this?

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c42b6

First time asking on Stackoverflow... Please let me know if my question was not in the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in practice you have more complicated data and there may be overlapping time intervals, for example:

table: enablement_changes

| user_id | start_at | end_at | enablement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 189 | 2020-12-12 | 2021-10-15 | disabled |
| 189 | **2020-12-20** | **2021-02-10** | **enabled** |
| 189 | 2021-10-15 | 2050-01-01 | enabled |

I recommend a more complex solution:

```
WITH _k AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS n
), _points AS (
  SELECT user_id, CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN start_at ELSE end_at END AS date_point, n
    FROM company_changes
   CROSS JOIN _k
   UNION
  SELECT user_id, CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN start_at ELSE end_at END AS date_point, n
    FROM enablement_changes
   CROSS JOIN _k
), _drank AS (
  SELECT p.user_id, p.date_point, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY p.user_id ORDER BY p.date_point) AS dr
    FROM _points AS p
   GROUP BY p.user_id, p.date_point
)
SELECT d1.user_id, d1.date_point AS start_at, d2.date_point AS end_at, c.company_id, MAX(s.status) AS status -- or MIN if status disabled is stronger than enabled in the same time
  FROM _drank AS d1
  JOIN _drank AS d2 ON d1.dr = d2.dr-1 AND d1.user_id = d2.user_id
  LEFT JOIN company_changes AS c    ON d1.user_id = c.user_id AND d1.date_point < c.end_at AND c.start_at < d2.date_point 
  LEFT JOIN enablement_changes AS s ON d1.user_id = s.user_id AND d1.date_point < s.end_at AND s.start_at < d2.date_point 
 GROUP BY d1.user_id, d1.date_point, d2.date_point, c.company_id
 ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=368a4d939f851c086849b284af58ddfa)**

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `JOIN` and `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT c.user_id 
       ,GREATEST(c.start_at, e.start_at) AS start_at
       ,LEAST(c.end_at, e.end_at) AS end_at
       ,c.company_id 
       ,e.status
FROM company_changes c
JOIN enablement_changes e
  ON (c.start_at BETWEEN e.start_at AND e.end_at
    OR c.end_at BETWEEN e.start_at AND e.end_at)
    AND c.user_id = e.user_id
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f2716eb5666c392e39246640891fb12f)**

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lukasz solution is good.

The but will match rows where the `c` table end time matches the start time of `e` table. Often datetime ranges want to be inclusive of `start` but not matching on `end` otherwise you will get two rows.

And it will miss any joins where the `c` start and end after the `e` table rows, but you want a match of the sub set. This latter point depend on if you are doing a dense match (there are always rows for all time) or a sparse match (only rows for some of the time)

The first problem can be fixed with an extra check:

```
SELECT c.user_id 
       ,GREATEST(c.start_at, e.start_at) AS start_at
       ,LEAST(c.end_at, e.end_at) AS end_at
       ,c.company_id 
       ,e.status
FROM company_changes c
JOIN enablement_changes e
  ON (c.start_at BETWEEN e.start_at AND e.end_at AND c.start_at < e.end_at
    OR c.end_at BETWEEN e.start_at AND e.end_at AND c.end_at >  e.start_at )
    AND c.user_id = e.user_id
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Where-as to match sparse matches you need.

```
SELECT c.user_id 
       ,GREATEST(c.start_at, e.start_at) AS start_at
       ,LEAST(c.end_at, e.end_at) AS end_at
       ,c.company_id 
       ,e.status
FROM company_changes c
JOIN enablement_changes e
    ON c.user_id = e.user_id
        AND (c.end_at > e.start AND c.start_at < e.end_at)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

On really large tables with large ranges the later code can be costly